# Coffee and health

Tags: health, coffee-culture

Does coffee induce these problems in an individual?
1. Coffee is also one of the cause for premature graying of hairs.
2. Coffee can induce insomnia.
3. Coffee can turn your teeth yellow.

Please share your thoughts on this!

Comment: I believe this is more of a topic for discussion rather than a question that has a correct answer, but nonetheless, I've taken a stab at it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Coffee! I've elected to close this question as it's essentially 3 separate questions rolled into one. Please feel free to post each question individually, so that they can be better answered and in greater detail.

Comment: Okey I will do !!

Answer (score 2):

1. I have to imagine the graying of hair is hereditary. Source: I've been drinking coffee for 20+ years with no sign of grays (approaching 40 now).
2. If consumed at the incorrect time, yes.
3. Sure, it can certainly yellow teeth over time, but I think this also comes down to genetics and personal hygiene - strength of tooth enamel, frequency of and care when brushing teeth, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think there's any scientific evidence that can back this up.
2. Coffee has caffeine, and caffeine is a stimulant. Stimulants, by definition, induce insomnia, but fortunately, caffeine is a pretty mild stimulant with a short half-life, so you should be fine as long as you don't drink a ton right before bed. Everyone's different, though, and some people are more sensitive than others.
3. Yes, it can stain your teeth. Brush regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Predisposition to coffee drinking in genetic by itself. If one finds that he or she has trouble getting sleep because of coffee, then the drink isn't for them.

Health benefits and research thereof on good-tasting black coffee has increased with time in recent years. To say that coffee in general may negatively affect general population is equivalently... a hasty generalization. Just don't drink the second-most-traded-commodity-next-to-oil if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

1.I have yet to come across solid research that backs up the fact that drinking coffee causes leads to grey hair.

2.Caffeine can keep you awake however if you build up a tolerance to it the effect may well in fact lessen. http://www.livestrong.com/article/521380-how-many-hours-does-caffeine-keep-you-awake/

3.Many substances stain teeth including coffee although every one's degree is different. One tip I have is to drink your coffee through a straw as it lessens the amount of contact of coffee to your teeth.  Just be careful not to burn your tongue.